# PHP: 'java' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, php, exec

I'm trying to run a .jar application from PHP using exec:

```
exec('java -jar parser.jar $inputstring 2>&1', $output);
```

I can get it to run on cmd, and java -version returns so I have java installed. It seems like this is a path issue, but I am at my wits end.

I've tried specifying the full path, adding C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin; to System Variables, using shell_exec, no avail. I get the same error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show how you added the full path. there's spaces in there. if you didn't quote the path, e.g. `shell_exec('"C:\Program files\....")`, then you'll be attempting to run a program named `c:\program.exe`, with argument `files\....`

Comment: I have: shell_exec('"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" -jar parser.jar $inputstring 2>&1');
If I don't have 2>&1 it's blank. With it I get the same 'java' not recognized error.

Comment: 2>&1 redirects stderr to stdout, which is why you get the error message. shell_exec only returns stdout, so you'd never see the error message.

Comment: You need to escape your backslashes. shell_exec ('"C:\\Program Files\\...

Comment: Try to echo the ``$PATH`` environement variable and see whether java is really in your path. Does the PHP script run under the same user as your cmd line test?

Comment: Did you quote the path using " when you specify the full path? such as "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe" -version

Comment: By the way you could try prepending `cmd /c` like this: exec('cmd /c "java -version"')

Answer (score 1):

Use this....

```
exec('java -jar parser.jar '.$inputstring.'2>&1', $output);
or
shell_exec("java -jar parser.jar $inputstring 2>&1 $output");
or
string exec ( 'java -jar parser.jar'  [, array &$output [, int &$return_var ]] )
```